# 'str' object has no attribute 'META' error while returning a JsonResponse

Tags: django, django-views, httpresponse, jsonresponse

I want to return a JsonResponse/HttpResponse from my Django views function. However I am getting 'str' object has no attribute 'META' error. The code for the function is given below.

```
def search(request):

    queryset_list = Influencer.objects.orderby('username')
    if 'username' in request.GET:
        username = request.GET['username']
        if username:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(username__iexact=username)

    #Full Name
    if 'fullname' in request.GET:
        fullname = request.GET['fullname']
        if fullname:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(full_name__iexact=fullname)
     context = {
        'listings':queryset_list,
        'values':request.GET
    }

    filtered_data = serializers.serialize("json",context)    

    return JsonResponse(filtered_data)
```

Comment: try this:`return JsonResponse(context)`

Comment: It gives the following error ```Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable```

Comment: post the `Influencer` model code.

Comment: ```class Influencer(models.Model):full_name = models.CharField('Full Name',max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField('Username',max_length=100,unique=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/%Y/%m/%d/',blank=True)
    email_id = models.EmailField('Email Id',blank=True)
    external_url = models.URLField('External URL')
    # instagram_url = models.URLField('Instagram URL',null=True,blank=True)
    location_city = models.CharField('Location City',max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    categories = MultiSelectField(choices = CATEGORIES,max_length=300)```

Comment: try this one: `'values': dict(request.GET)`

Comment: same error ```Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of serializing the context I serialized the query_list obtained and the function worked correctly.
The code after the last if statement should be this.

```
 serialized_list = serializers.serialize('json',queryset_list)

 return HttpResponse(serialized_list, content_type='application/json')
```